Reverse Engineering S/EX RE-MAN BOARD INTERFACE SR2 SL (MRD-45-2276)
S/EX RE-MAN BOARD INTERFACE SR2 SL (MRD-45-2276)
How can I access the raw data sent by the sensors to this board?
I also need the data sheet and schematic information of the board.

Welcome to SE/RE! Please [edit] your question to add links to any documentation (descriptions, images, whatever you have) of the board and the sensors. -- What did you try for now? Did you record raw data or waves? Did you start to draw a (partial) schematic? What kind of device uses this board for what purpose?
